# How to use function output as a conditional of IF ELSE or Ternary operator

Tags: flutter, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

So for some background, I implemented a function that reads from Firebase's real-time database and returns a child node. I have built a button that is meant to check if that function returns the object or null if the function returns an object I want the snack bar to display a message.

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (validateUsername() != null) {
                print("conditional: test");
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                    content: Text(
                        "Username has been taken please try a different one"),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 5)));
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
```

I had some success with the function by turning it into an async function

```
  validateUsername() async {
final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("/takenUsernames");
await database
    .child(_usernameController.text.trim())
    .once()
    .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
  final snapShot = event.snapshot;
  final value = snapShot.value;
  print("function result: $value");
  return value;
});
```

}
When I turn it to an async function the snack bar displays the message but unfortunately even when the conditional is equal to a null, it for some reason continues to display the message and prints the "test"[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuWVy.png). But if I were to try taking away the async the snack bar doesn't print and the "test" in the conditional doesn't print.[non-async output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8vBb.png)

Any help would be appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: Where did you use the async await?

Comment: in the above validateUsername() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from @WilsonToribio, I was able to use the information he gave and also implement a few changes to the `validateUsername()` function
as seen here

```
  validateUsername() async {
try {
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("/usernames");
  final response = await database
      .child(_usernameController.text.trim())
      .once()
      .then((event) {
    final dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;
    if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      return dataSnapshot.value;
    }
  });
  return response;
} catch (e) {
  print("err $e");
  return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, using the await in a variable will wait for the value then the if will evaluate what the result.

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  String validation = await validateUsername(); // I used type String but you should use the type that will be return.
                  if (validation != null) {
                    print("conditional: test");
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                            "Username has been taken please try a different one"),
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 5)));
                  } else {
                    return;
                  }
                },
            )
```

Comment: I like the idea but unfortunately, it doesn't even print the "test" conditional or display a snack bar. Any other ideas?

Comment: Would you print validation after `String validation = await validateUsername();` ?

Comment: I did and I noticed something strange, even tho within the function I print and return the value. When I try to print it right after `String validation = await validateUsername();` it prints as null which I don't understand. What do you think? (sorry for the delay I'm in a math class lol)

Comment: What value type is returning in the function?

Comment: its a value of a key from firebase I tried to use toSting() method on it but it errors out saying that (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: If you did the print inside `validateUsername()` so the value is coming null or the query is not being found for some reason, so first verify that your are receiving a valid value type, to check what is going on.

Comment: Im sure the database is being read and is printing the value of the ref inside the validateUsername() function but is I said in the onPressed right after `String validation = await validateUsername();` but before the conditional is printing out as null

Comment: So check what is the type of the value returned, `String validation = await validateUsername();` because validation is type String, verify if is type int, Map, etc, so you will adjust the variable to the return type.

Comment: it originally said object? but when I try and use the toString() method and set it as a String its says the above (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: thanks for your help I was able to figure it out using the info you gave and some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

add try/catch

```
 validateUsername() async {
try {
final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("/takenUsernames");
await database
    .child(_usernameController.text.trim())
    .once()
    .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
  final snapShot = event.snapshot;
  final value = snapShot.value;
  print("function result: $value");
  return value;
});
} catch(e) {
  print("err $e");
  return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: I attempted that but it didn't solve the problem. It does the same thing of ignoring the conditions != null and prints even when equal to null. Any other ideas?

Comment: add also async in `onPressed` and call async function with `await`

Comment: I just tried that but no luck now it doesn't even print the "test" conditional or display the snack bar.

Comment: what do you see in run console? you should have seen the error by`print("err $e");`, I think your error into `await database
    .child(_usernameController.text.trim())
    .once()
    .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
  final snapShot = event.snapshot;
  final value = snapShot.value;
  print("function result: $value");
  return value;
});`

Comment: The function never fails so it is not catching an error. The problem now is that even tho the function validateUsername() returns a value and prints it from inside the function. When I try to use it in a conditional or print it outside the function it registers it as null.